# How to Change Role of User from Partner User to Partner Manager User?

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-community, partner-communities, partner-portal

We have a partner community setup with Enabled Partner Users. We have recently changed the communities settings for Number of partner roles to 2, It was 1 before.

All users currently have partner user role. We want to change few users role to partner Manager but when we edit a user to change its role to Partner Manager User, This role does not show up in the role drop-down. We can only see one role in drop-down which is Partner User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this without duplicating(creating new accounts) the existing Accounts and creating new Contacts and then recreating the existing communtiy users and deactivating the ones that already preexists.

The other option i think is raising a case with Salesforce support to see if they have any magic to make this work.

> At high level it requires creation of roles and subordinates under the hood. Unfortunately based on those community settings of number of roles these roles are auto created and group object (Note roles are a type in that object) is locked and does not allow to add in roles manually.